# Specify the order of a multiindex in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a panda's data frame with a multiindex (that will be eventually written to a formatted Excel file), similar to the following:

```
first  second
one    bar      -0.292975
       baz      -0.176312
       foo      -0.458917
       qux       0.966987
two    bar       1.615486
       baz       0.875479
       foo      -3.092365
       qux      -2.348825
```

I would like to specify the order of the second index (note `baz` is always at the bottom), like so:

```
first  second
one    bar      -0.292975
       foo      -0.458917
       qux       0.966987
       baz      -0.176312
two    bar       1.615486
       foo      -3.092365
       qux      -2.348825
       baz       0.875479
```

I tried to slice the data frame like this, but it does not change the output:

`myDF.loc[(slice(None),['bar','foo', 'qux', 'baz']),:]`

I tried to change the index itself

`myDF.index.levels[1] = pd.Index(['bar','foo', 'qux', 'baz'])`

but error out with:

> TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `reindex` your data *(frame/Series)* like so:

```
new_index = ['bar','foo', 'qux', 'baz']
v.reindex(new_index, level=1)

#first  second
#one    bar      -0.292975
#       foo      -0.458917
#       qux       0.966987
#       baz      -0.176312
#two    bar       1.615486
#       foo      -3.092365
#       qux      -2.348825
#       baz       0.875479
#Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @MaxU I didn't know either. Just discovered this. :)-