# How to manually specify the sort order for a MultiIndex?

Tags: pandas

How can I specify the sort order for a `MultiIndex`

```
                    2023    2024    
BU        State             
--------------------------------
Mfg         med        1       2
            low        3       4
            high       5       6
Sales       med        a       b
            low        c       d
            high       e       f
Acct        med        9       8
            low        7       6
            high       5       4
```

My goal is to:

- manually provide the sort order for the first index field (i.e. Sales -> Mfg -> Acct)
- manually provide the sort order for the second index field (i.e, low -> med -> high)

Is this possible with Pandas [sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)?  If so, how can I do this?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668444/specify-the-order-of-a-multiindex-in-python-pandas) question, but it is only specifying the sort order for the second index field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
df = df.reindex(['Sales', 'Mfg', 'Acct'], level=0)
df = df.reindex(['low', 'med', 'high'], level=1)
```